# Deploying Helm Chart to Rancher managed Kubernetes cluster does not show pods in a project in the GUI

Tags: rancher

I have created a new namespace using Kubectl. I have then successfully deployed a basic Nginx Helm chart (using Helm3) into the new namespace. I can port forward and see the nginx happily running, and I can see the namespace listed in the Rancher UI. However, there is no Project associated with the Helm Release so I can't see the running workloads/pods through Rancher. Am I looking in the wrong place, or will all Helm Releases/deployments not show up on the Rancher UI as workloads?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. When I created the namespace using Kubectl it did not assign it to a Rancher project. I went into the UI and moved the namespace into an existing Project and then was able to see all the Pods/Workloads etc.

Is "Project" a Rancher specific term, or is it a Kubernetes term/object?

Comment: The concept of 'Project' is Rancher specific.